# Heroku Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Tags: javascript, heroku

i am making an application in angular, runs fine locally but when i try to deploy it with heroku, shows the next error:

```
 Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

the code looks like this:

```
const express= require('express'),
path= require('path');

const app =express();

app.use(express.static('./dist/re-mi'));

app.get('/*', (req,res)=>{
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/myapp/index.html'));
});

var port_number = server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.listen(port_number);
```

i also see other questions with the same error but no answer works for me

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `port_number` variable you have is not set correctly. If your full code is posted, then the variable `server` is not defined anywhere. 
That is from the line

```
var port_number = server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Even if `server` is defined, it seems unlikely that server.listen would return the port number that it is listening on. 
I think you would want:

```
var port_number = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port_number);
```

Comment: Is your `server` variable defined in the file somewhere? I am thinking that the line with that call (`server.listen`) will cause an error, so that the app.listen() call is not getting executed. I was thinking, if you put a callback function in the app.listen call, (the second argument, after the port_number), that console.logs to the screen, just to make sure it is running.

`

app.listen(port_number, () => {
  console.log("API Server now listening on PORT " + port_number + "!);
});
`